# when using pulseaudio, internal sink not selectable

Tags: pulseaudio

using unity-control-center/sound, there is only a selection for the HDMI audio output, not for the internal sound.  the internal sound has jacks on the back of the mother board.  What do I need to do to be able to select the internal sound?

Answer (score 0):

The internal sound card may not be detected or have the required drivers.

You must report the dmesg log found in /var/log/dmesg which can contain valuable information about hardware initialisation (or failure of)